# JavaScript regex field value

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm trying to see if a value does not equal something with this code

```
if !(regx.test(field.value))
```

I know that 
    if (regx.test(field.value))
this works fine, I would just like it to do something if it does not match.

Comment: What is `field.value` containing? btw you have to write `!` into `if` statement. Like this `if(!regx.test(field.value))`

Comment: developer tools console would have an error message, something like `SyntaxError: missing ( before condition` - if you develop, get to know and love the developer tools, available in all good browsers as a standard feature, usually invoked by using the F12 key

Comment: move the `!` inside the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an `else` statement:

```
if (!regx.test(field.value)) {
   console.log('does not match');
} else {
   console.log('it matches!');
}
```

Comment: OP needs `does not match` in the `if` block, not `else` block.